# How to produce a .txt file with user input

Tags: javascript, html, css, file

so I've been trying my best to figure out how to take input provided by the user (mostly integers with a few strings here and there) and  write it to a .txt file. The system would then take that .txt file and do something with it, but no need to worry about that just yet.

I currently have the html and css written so the user can input all of their information into the correct input boxes. I also have a submit button at the bottom.

Ideally, I would want the .txt file to either open with all of the user input inserted neatly in it, or to be saved in order to be ready to be used in another way.

Comment: Are you trying to save locally on the client (answer: you can't), or on the server?

Comment: which server/technology do you use for your server?

Comment: Well the thing is that I would be using that .txt file to then be used with a program which runs entirely on C. The program would take in the .txt file and run it through it's own functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of both client and server technologies.
On your browser, client using HTML set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form, file will be sent using `post`.

```
<form id="uploadfile" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="#">
   <input id="file" name="file" type="file" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

At your server you need get the file and perform your operation (which may vary by your server technology).

If instead you need only need a client solution you could have a look at

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

which is a reasonable solution if you need to generate files / saving files that shouldn't be sent to an external server.

Comment: So I wrote that code in, and all it does is ask for a file to be submitted and a submit form function. How would I go about making it possible for all the user's inputs to be written on the .txt file when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: Do you mean you need only a client solution (browser) where you create the .txt file without server support? I made an edit to my anser